# Returning properties on a Javascript Constructor function

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to solve a problem where I have the following piece of code:

```
var piggie = new Animal(Animal.PIG);
```

How can a Constructor function (new Animal) also be an Object with properties (Animal.PIG)?

I have tried this solution:

```
function Animal(type) {
    this.typeOf = type;

    return {
        PIG: 'Pig'   
    };
}
```

But Animal.PIG is undefined? JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bufr2b4c/

Comment: You cannot return something from a constructor, when called with new, it returns the newly constructed object, `this`

Comment: this is not the way, just go to MDN in google and read litle bit, you do not need SO for this.

Comment: @JuanMendes — You can, it's just a terrible idea and it returns what you say instead of `this` which makes using a constructor function pointless.

Comment: @Quentin I'll be darned http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/cercykLb/ I knew I should have tested before saying so, I thought I had heard something about that.

Answer (score 1):

For `Animal.PIG` to have a value, you have to create a property on the constructor function itself.

```
function Animal(type) {
    this.typeOf = type;
}

Animal.PIG = "Pig";
```

Your code is creating an object when the constructor runs and setting PIG on *that* object. (And discarding the constructed Animal instance as you go).

Answer (score 0):

You ned execute `console.log((new Animal).PIG); //It's done!` because you are accessing to a property of an object (you need create this object. Therefore you needs to use **NEW**)

```
function Animal(type) {
    this.typeOf = type;

    return {
        PIG: 'Pig'   
    };
}

console.log(new Animal);
console.log((new Animal).PIG); //this is undefined, but why?

console.log(typeof Animal);             // "function"
console.log(Animal instanceof Object);  // true
```

### EDITED

You can use something like below:

```
function Color(col) {   
   this.color = col;
   this.getColor = function() {
       return this.color;
   }
}

var blueBox = new Color("blue");
alert(blueBox.getColor()); // will alert blue
alert(blueBox.color); // will alert blue
```